# Jenkins build is passed even if jmeter duration assertion fails

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am running jmeter using jenkins, i have duration assertion of 300ms in my script. The assertion is working fine, as my jmeter result is showing error but the jenkins build still passes.

[image: Jenkins build summary]

Is there any way to fail my build in case of error in jmeter result ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define [Error Threshold](https://performanceengineeringsite.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/automating-jmeter-run-using-jenkins-ci-cd/)

> The Error Threshold marks the the build as unstable or failed if the amount of errors will exceed the specified value.
>
> Use error thresholds on single build – Define error thresholds in % for the current build.

[image]

Comment: in that case .jtl file is not updated on each run. if my build has failed once, it is failing again even though there are no errors.

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri there's an error in the image you posted

Comment: i am not talking about this image but when i am running my build now the scenario in above comment is happening.

Comment: @ShivyeshAgnihotri you need to define in jmeter command the jtl report as `-l Test.jtl`

Answer (score 0):

The options are in:

1. Configure error threshold in [Performance Plugin GUI](http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/RunTests.html)

   [image]
2. Jenkins considers build passed when it returns 0 [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), you can "tell" JMeter to exit with non-zero exit code by adding JSR223 Listener and using the following code:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       System.out.println("Test failure, exiting...")
       System.exit(1)
   }
   ```

   where `prev` stands for parent [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance which gives you control over parent [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) response code, message, data, etc.  Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api) shortcuts available for [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)

   it will result in the following behaviour:

   [image]

   and this `1` status code will cause Jenkins build failure
3. Alternative solution for point 2 would be using [Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper for your JMeter test, it provides handly [Pass/Fail Criteria](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/)  subsystem which provides flexible way of defining custom thresholds for considering your test as failed